How to reuse the genvar in Verilog?
This question was raised when I tried to create a left shifter in gate level, using verilog.
the requirement is to come up with a shifter, that

the user can specify the shift amount in binary, up to 32 (10000b)
supports left shift, meaning shift the value of a[0] to a[1], and fill a[0] with 1'b0, given the shift amount is 00001; if the shift amount is 00000 then the value remains unchanged.

I use multiplexers to help me do the shifting. Here's the schematic of the mux I'm using, it's a screenshot from a video of my Professor Kaushik Patra
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uDFf6bef_U&ab_channel=KaushikPatra%27sSJSUClassroom
module's name: MUX1_2x1
Here's a demonstration from Dr.Patra of a shifter supporting a 2 bits shift amount
"S0" being the first bit of the shift amount, if the value of the shift amount bit is 1 then we perform the shift at that "stage" (i.e so a four-bit shifter have 4 stages, that
"S0",the first shift bit is "stage 1" shift, which shifts 2^0 (1bit) if shifted
"S1" the  second shift bit is "stage 2" shift, which shifts 2^1 (2bits) if shifted
third shift bit is "stage 3" shift, which shifts 2^2 (4bits)
forth shift bit is "stage 4" shift, which shifts 2^3 (8bits), so on and so forth)
2 bit left shifter scheme
so, as I was doing the assignment, I want to reuse the genvar that I declared in my generation block
//port list of MUX1_2x1: (Y,I0, I1, S)
// Y: output, I0, I1: input, S: control signal
// st1_result is a wire
//D[] is input of the shifter
//I0 is not shift, I1 is shift
genvar i; //for normal shifting bits
genvar j; //for zero filling bits
generate
    begin: first_stage_shift //shift amount = 1
        // first bit
        MUX1_2x1 inst_0(st1_result[0], D[0], 1'b0, S[0]);
        
        for (i = 1; i<32; i = i+1)
            MUX1_2x1 inst_1(st1_result[i], D[i], D[i-1], S[0]);
    end
// this is the line that has error (81)
    i=0; //reset the genvar
    begin: second_stage_shift //shift amount = 2
        // first bit 
        MUX1_2x1 inst_0(st2_result[0], St1_result[0], 1'b0, S[1]);
        // second bit 
        MUX1_2x1 inst_1(st2_result[1], St1_result[1], 1'b0, S[1]);
        
        for (i = 2; i<32; i = i+1)
            MUX1_2x1 inst_1(st2_result[i], st1_result[i], st1_result[i-2], S[1]);
    end

as in the screenshot, I want to reset the genvar by writing i=0, so that I can use it in the next for loop, however, I get this error at line 81:
** Error: (vlog-13069) D:/barrel_shifter.v(81): near "=": syntax error, unexpected '='.
** Error: D:/barrel_shifter.v(81): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'i'. Is there a missing '::'?

I search on the web a bit, but I didn't find what what i was looking for.
Is it possible to reuse/reset the genvar in verilog, instead of declaring multiple genvars?

@toolic: Wouldn't i be 32 because the first for loop looped 31 times, and the last iteration makes i ==32? edit: Oh I see what you mean.

Thank you for pointing that out, I didn't notice that, but I'm still interested in seeing if there's a way to reset the genvar just out of curiosity

Generate statements are not procedural code. Generate-for loops get unrolled and the i gets replaced with a constant.
You only need multiple genvar declarations if you plan to nest the for loops, which is not the case here. You can also put the genvar declaration as part of the for loop.
MUX1_2x1 inst_0(st1_result[0], D[0], 1'b0, S[0]);     
for (genvar i = 1; i<32; i = i+1) begin : first_loop
            MUX1_2x1 inst_1(st1_result[i], D[i], D[i-1], S[0]);
end

MUX1_2x1 inst_0(st2_result[0], St1_result[0], 1'b0, S[1]);
MUX1_2x1 inst_1(st2_result[1], St1_result[1], 1'b0, S[1]);
for (genvar i = 2; i<32; i = i+1) begin : second_loop
   MUX1_2x1 inst_1(st2_result[i], st1_result[i], st1_result[i-2], S[1]);
end

If you need a value that is a based on the loop variable, declare a parameter.
for (genvar i = 2; i<32; i = i+1) begin : second_loop
   parameter i_minus_2 = i-2; // could be a function call too
   MUX1_2x1 inst_1(st2_result[i], st1_result[i], st1_result[i_minus_2], S[1]);
end


Hello, dave_59, Thank you for your answer, it's very helpful! Now I have a better understanding of the generate statement, especially putting the genvar inside the for, I have no idea we can do that :D
